# Image Links in HTA / HTML

Tags: html, hta

I have an HTA application which has an image. When clicked on this image calls a sub. When an 'Enter' Key is hit another sub is called.

The problem here is when an Enter key is hit both the subs are called.

See the code below for example ...

```
<head>

<HTA:APPLICATION>



</head>


<script language="VBScript">

Sub EnterKey

    If window.event.Keycode = 13 then
        MsgBox "Enter was pressed"
    End If

    If window.event.Keycode = 27 then
        MsgBox "Escape was pressed"
    End If

End Sub

Sub DeleteThis
    MsgBox "Image was clicked"
End Sub

</script>

<body onkeypress="EnterKey">

<input type="image" height="27" width="27" onclick="DeleteThis" src="Search.png" alt="Database Search">

</body>
```

When 'Enter' key is hit both "Image was clicked" & "Enter was pressed" gets displayed. I do not want the "Image was clicked" message to be displayed when 'Enter' is clicked.

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Not exactly related, but scripts should be placed either in the `head` or in the `body`, not between them.

Comment: @Teemu I dont understand how you can have the script header within the Head and body headers, doesnt make sense.

Comment: It does make sense, when you find out, that there's no such a thing like "script header" in HTML. [`<html>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html): "`Permitted content: One <head> element, followed by one <body> element.`"

Comment: @Teemu Did i forget to mention HTA ?

Comment: No you didn't, but HTA doesn't make any difference, it's still HTML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i figured this out, i have changed the below code for the image link

```
<input type="image" height="27" width="27" onclick="DeleteThis" src="Search.png" alt="Database Search">
```

to

```
<img src="search.png" alt="Database Search" width="27" height="27" onclick="DeleteThis">
```

Apparently it depends on the tag one uses ...

Answer (score 2):

You could either remove `onclick="DeleteThis"` to prevent that function from being called at all.

Or you have to implement a condition into the function `DeleteThis`, to prevent the output if the key pressed was the enter key.

```
Sub DeleteThis
    If window.event.Keycode != 13 then
        MsgBox "Image was clicked"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When i put "msgbox window.event.Keycode" i get the output as '0' and not 13, which is strange. Then again, clicking on the image has to display that message, which would not work if i put a condition

Comment: Who knows what an IE does…